# How to access a service endpoint in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

On Azure, I have:

- a virtual network A with some IP address range 10.1.0.0/16
- a virtual Windows machine in network A with an IP address of 10.1.0.1.
- an Azure Database for MySQL server

In the firewall rules for the Database for MySQL server I have added the virtual network A. The portal created a service endpoint Microsoft.sql in my network A then.

What I address or DNS name would my virtual Windows machine have to use in order to access the database server?

Answer (score 0):

It’s normal DNS address.

It’ll still resolve to its regular IP address but the connectivity to it will go via the service connection in your subnet.

Comment: I guess you mean DNS-Name? What's the point of the service endpoint then? I could just use the "public" route?

Comment: It allows you to keep the data on the Azure network as well as only allow your vent to access it.  See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview#key-benefits

Comment: I should clarify further.  Using the service endpoint, the MySQL Database sees connections coming from the private IP of your server and you can firewall accordingly.  Without it, the connections come from a pool of public IPs that you don’t have control over unless you’ve allocated public IPs to the hosts.